# Verify word document by vbscripting

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Do you think vba will help me learn how to verify a word document by vbscripting. Or I have to strictly learn vb scripting for word documents. My main problem is I want to start verifying from line 7 for example and then exit document once I am done. I do not want to verify till the end of document. Please let me know how to do it.

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strFilePath)
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
For i =0 to 1

    objSelection.Find.Text =Date 'Today's Date
        objSelection.Find.Forward = TRUE
        objSelection.Find.MatchWholeWord = TRUE

        If objSelection.Find.Execute Then
           Call Verification(True, True,"The search string was found."&i, "")
        Else
           Call Verification(True, False,"The search string was not found.", "")
    End If
Next
objWord.Quit 0
```

Comment: until where or when do you want to verify

Comment: Sorry I meant:  Please disregard the above comment. I meant to say that in word document you will not have a range such as in Excel so if I wanted to verify created date and transmission date that are both in one line.I cannot do that with above script since it is matching all the dates in the document created and transmitted and so I do not know which one it matched.

Comment: Could you upload or paste the document or the relevant parts which may contain all the test cases.